# Filtering an inner field within GenericForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class ItemA(models.Model):
   catagory_id = model.ForeignKey('Category')

class ItemB(models.Model):
   catagory_id = model.ForeignKey('Category')

class Rate(model.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3)
```

So I have two types of Items, `ItemA` and `ItemB` both have `catagory_id` as a fieid.

The Rate model, is a `GenericForignKey`. What I want to have is one Rate table which rate any of the items which are type `ItemA` and `ItemB`.

My problem is that I would like to filter at a given moment , all items from the Rate table which are in a specific category.

Something like that :

```
item = Rate.objects.filter(content_object__catagory_id=1)
```

But I can't do that.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an easy way to do this in one query because `content_object` which has been enabled by `GenericForeignKey` cannot be used in filters as such.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey):

> Due to the way `GenericForeignKey` is implemented, you cannot use such fields directly with filters (`filter()` and `exclude()`, for example) via the database API. Because a `GenericForeignKey` isn’t a normal field object, these examples will not work:
>
> ```
> # This will fail
> >>> TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_object=guido)
> # This will also fail
> >>> TaggedItem.objects.get(content_object=guido)
> ```

---

Considering this, here is how I would approach it:

I would get all the ids for `ItemA` and `ItemB` which have that specific `category_id`:

```
item_a_ids = list(ItemA.objects.filter(category_id=category_id).values_list('pk', flat=True))
item_b_ids = list(ItemB.objects.filter(category_id=category_id).values_list('pk', flat=True))

# combine these two id lists
all_item_ids = item_a_ids + item_b_ids

# now that we have these let's filter the Rate objects with __in operator
rates = Rate.objects.filter(object_id__in=all_item_ids)
```